# Measure page load/processing time in ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to run this php script `http://db2express/imacs/radek/3.1/rationalTest.php?mode=create`

The processing time is about 10mins or so and it `streams` out to the browser output of what it does. It's creating and setting up and a database, creating indexes etc.

How can I **measure** how long it **takes** to process which means fully load this page?

I need to run the page from ruby. Also capture the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're on a unix-like, you could just do

```
time curl "http://db2express/imacs/radek/3.1/rationalTest.php?mode=create" > output.html
```

If you really need to do it from ruby...

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'date'

url = "http://db2express/imacs/radek/3.1/rationalTest.php?mode=create"

start = Time.new
f = open(url).read
stop = Time.new

puts "Time elapsed: #{stop - start} seconds"
puts "The content of the file is:\n#{f}"
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean here - if you mean that you need to run this script in ruby rather than opening the files as Bill shows (it really needs to be noted though that this should work fine) you can use the exec() command.